# Efficient way to handle date between Controller and view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an app that reads through a table of data and based on the name of the person, does a for each loop, producing a card for each job that is assigned to that user.

EG.

```
    user1  Job 1
    user1  Job 2
    user2  Job 3
    user3  Job 4
    ... could be 3000 plus records here with up to 40/50 users
```

The controller collects the data from the table and sends it in bulk to the view for a foreach user statment to produce the code for each user then for each Job where it matches the user.

Controller code:

```
function dash() 
{

        if($user = Auth::user())
        {
            $users=  User::all();
            $jobs=  Job::all();
            
            return view('jobview', compact('users','jobs'));    

        }
        if(Auth::guest())
        {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
}
```

The view code is simple:

```
@foreach($users as $user)        
            @foreach($jobs as $job)
                @if ($job->technician == $user->id)
                <!--The code in this include generates a few lines of code to create the card-->
                    @include('layouts/sublayouts.jobscard')  
                @endif
            @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The core problem is, there can be over 3000 cards (all need to be visable at the same time) and there can be 40 users to show.

I assume the slowness is the for each loop being done in the view?

Any guidance would be appriciated.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Have a read at [One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) Relationship

Answer (score 0):

Try something like, this will do the comparasion when getting the data from the database instead, should be alot faster:

```
$user_id = Auth::user() -> id;
$jobs = Job::Where('technician', '=', $user_id)->get();
return view('jobview', compact('jobs'));
```

**EDIT**:

In response to comment for all Jobs, do an inverse One-to-many relationship, for example:

```
//Job Model
class Job extends Model
{
    public function technician()
    {
        return $this->belongTo('App\User');
    }
}
    
//Controller
$jobs= App\Job::All();
return('jobview', compact('jobs')

//View
@foreach($jobs as $job)
    {{ $job -> technician -> [Insert Some User property you want here] }}
    {{ $job -> jobName }}
```

And if you want to "group" them by user simply do `orderBy('technician')` in your controller.
Take a closer read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Thanks for the response, the trouble is thus page shows all users and all jobs associated to each user. This would only work for a single user?